# completion-kill-region breaks rectangle-mark-mode

Tags: completion, rectangle

When using dynamic completion, `rectangle-mark-mode` is broken, in so far as `C-w` no longer respects just killing the rectangle but instead kills the usual full (non-rectangular) region.

`M-w` on the other hand works, because it is the original function, while `C-w` is overloaded with `completion-kill-region`.

To test: try `C-w` after `C-x SPC` once bound to `kill-region` and once bound to `completion-kill-region` (or simply `M-x` the two functions with an active rectangular region).

I have "fixed" it in my `init.el` in the following hackish way

```
(add-hook 'rectangle-mark-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (if rectangle-mark-mode ;; entering...
            (if (not dynamic-completion-mode)
                (setq restore--dyncomplete nil)
              (setq restore--dyncomplete t)
              (dynamic-completion-mode -1))
          ;; ...else leaving
          (if restore--dyncomplete 
              (dynamic-completion-mode t)))))
```

What would be the right way to do it? Who to reach to have this fixed upstream? In the file it only says emacs-devel as the maintainer...

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: What @Stefan said. What you wrote here will make a good bug report, along with the info that `M-x report-emacs-bug` will automatically provide (Emacs build etc.).

Comment: Done that (the bug report...). I am still trying to find out what the right fix could be but somehow I don't understand it from the code. I fear I need to learn (again) how to make use of edebug...